# see if string starts with <!DOCTYPE

Tags: jquery

I'm getting ajax response from php page which starts with `<!DOCTYPE`

I want see if response string starts with `<!DOCTYPE` ,
how can I do it using response.match(pattern) or do I have to use something else.
Do I need to include double quotes?
please help.

Comment: You should rely on HTTP status codes.

Comment: @moonwave99 could you please elaborate that

Comment: Who's packaging the response into Javascript?  Are you building your own xhr fetch, or are you using jQuery or something else?  As moonwave99 suggested, you should be able to look at response status codes and content/type info that came back in the headers to know if you should expect HTML or something else.  The fact that you have the `response == 'ok'` check makes me wonder what the `response` object is?  Clarification of the scenario would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `test` function if you just want a boolean answer :

```
/^<!DOCTYPE/.test(response)
```